# How to see all site collections in a specific content DB

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I see all site collections associated in a specific Content db in SharePoint 2010?

Any advice or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: also sharepoint 2013

Comment: also SharePoint 2016

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All  -ContentDatabase contentdbname | select url, @{label="Size";Expression={$_.usage.storage}}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to speed this up when its used for only returning one site collection?

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved by

```
get-spsite -limit all | select url,contentdatabase
```

The output gets you all of your content databases and the site collections contained within. The -limit all would help if you have more than 100 site collections.

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution. But you could have said it in a nicer way..

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, just look in the documentation and here it goes: [SPContentDatabase.Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.sites.aspx).

Comment: is it possible to get all site collections under specific content database using powershell? if yes is there any documentation available?

Comment: @SPAdmin PowerShell can use other .NET assemblies, call the methods, access the properties, etc. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattbie/archive/2010/02/23/how-to-call-net-and-win32-methods-from-powershell-and-your-troubleshooting-packs.aspx

Comment: `(Get-SPContentDatabase -Identity contentdbname).Sites`