# output site collection url in a variable from contentdb

Tags: database, powershell, sharepoint

I am currently trying to get one site collection URL from my content db.

After researching I found:

[How to see all site collections in a specific content DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609964/how-to-see-all-site-collections-in-a-specific-content-db)

And after changing the accepted answer a tiny bit to get only 1 site collection and only the url and assigning it to a variable I have:

```
$mySiteURL = Get-SPSite -Limit 1  -ContentDatabase WSS_Content_DBNAME | select url
```

However, when I output this variable using `Write-Host $mySiteURL` I get:

```
@{Url=http://mysites.mydomain.local}
```

when I only want:

```
http://mysites.mydomain.local
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object array with an URL property. To dissolve the object and retain just the string you can use `-ExpandProperty`

```
$mySiteURL = Get-SPSite -Limit 1  -ContentDatabase WSS_Content_DBNAME | select-object -expandproperty url
```

This is one of the common gotcha's of PowerShell.