# how to find what looks at a content Database in SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There is plenty of documentation out there for looking up what content DB a site collection uses in SharePoint. However, I'm looking for the reverse. I have a specific DB, and I need to know where (what URL's) it's content is referenced or displayed.

We have a DB that has been partially corrupted and in need of restoring. It appears the only clean backup we have of it is relatively old. However, at first glance the library we know to be using it is lightly used. There has been no new content added to it since our backup was taken.

I am looking for a way to confirm that restoring from this backup wont unknowingly overwrite some critical data somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doing more digging, I did find another SO post that was able to get me the information I needed.

[How to see all site collections in a specific content DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609964/how-to-see-all-site-collections-in-a-specific-content-db)

```
-ContentDatabase contentdbname | select url, @{label="Size";Expression={$_.usage.storage}}
```

In navigating to the returned URL, I found recently added data. So that now rules out the restore.